# how to add new colume from original dataframe column - python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a new column with calcuation using data condition from original one.

data that I am using looks like ;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RqKd.png)

I wnat to calcuate number under the duration tap using 'type' columes, and
the outcome that i am expecting would be --

```
 team        date        (core-work/corework-duration)
resolution   2021-09-01   0.9043
resolution   2021-09-02   0.9385
```

I have been reasearching how to solove that issue, but I lost.....
please help me out
thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide both your input & output dataframes as text so others can copy them.

Comment: so you want only the difference between the rows that have the TYPE as core-work?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team':['Resolution', 'Resolution', 'Resolution', 'Resolution'], 
                   'date':['2021-09-01', '2021-09-01', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-02'], 
                   'Type':['Core-work', 'available', 'Core-work', 'available'], 
                   'duration': [218394, 23102, 225850, 14800]})
print(df)
```

```
         Team        date       Type  duration
0  Resolution  2021-09-01  Core-work    218394
1  Resolution  2021-09-01  available     23102
2  Resolution  2021-09-02  Core-work    225850
3  Resolution  2021-09-02  available     14800
```

Divide 'Core-work' duration by the sum of the durations for each Team-date group:

```
frac_df = df[df['Type'].eq('Core-work')].set_index(['Team', 'date'])[['duration']].div(df.groupby(['Team', 'date']).sum())

print(print(frac_df.reset_index()))
```

```
         Team        date  duration
0  Resolution  2021-09-01  0.904338
1  Resolution  2021-09-02  0.938500
```